# How to implement Wikitude API in iPhone Application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to implement the Wikitude API in my iPhone Application.
But while implementing this API in my application i got stuck in one point.
I am having one view controller in which i am having one button on clicking on which i want to open this [wikitudeAR start] as like
[self.view addSubview:[wikitudeAR start]];

But it is not working properly.
It is not showing the camera view ([wikitudeAR start]) which i want to show on clicking of button.

In sample application which you have provided with wikitude API is showing like 
[window addSubview:[wikitudeAR start]];

But i want to show the wikitudeAR view (wikitudeAR camera view) over my view and not over the main window.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi this works for me, 
in verificationDidSucceed add the controller to window:

```
    - (void) verificationDidSucceed { 
        //appDel is an AppDelegate shared instance of your application  
        [appDel.window addSubview: [wikitudeAR start]];
    }
```

then you can use show/hide functions to display the controller once you have "start" the controller. 
You can define an IBAction, if you have already start the controller just show this;

```
-(IBAction)startAR{

    if (wikitudeAR == nil) {
        wikitudeAR = [[WikitudeARViewController alloc] initWithDelegate:self applicationPackage:APPPACKAGE_WIKITUDE_ applicationKey:APPKEY_WIKITUDE_ applicationName:APPNAME_WIKITUDE_ developerName:APPDEVELOPER_WIKITUDE_];   
    }else {
        [wikitudeAR show];

    }
}
```

then call "hide" function to hide the controller.