# Shared instance of App -iPhone

Tags: iphone, instance, shared

How to create shared instance of  my app?
"appDel is an AppDelegate shared instance of your application"

Comment: What do you need to know exactly?

Comment: I cant understand this one:  //appDel is an AppDelegate shared instance of your application  
        [appDel.window addSubview: [wikitudeAR start]];

Comment: in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5128634/how-to-implement-wikitude-api-in-iphone-application/5146600#5146600

Comment: He is mentioning that `appDel` is the application delegate of the shared instance of the `UIApplication` which is obtained by doing `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]`.

Comment: so this should be ok:   [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].window addSubview: [wikitudeAR start]];
because is not!

Comment: Basically `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]` returns a `id<UIApplicationDelegate>` object which doesn't have a window object. You need to cast it to whatever your application delegate class is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to create shared instance of my app?

The application instance is created in the `UIApplicationMain` function. You can access this object by invoking the `sharedApplication` class method.

> "appDel is an AppDelegate shared
>   instance of your application"

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]` will give you a pointer to your application delegate.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to create it. The shared instance (singleton) is always there, assuming that you're using the standard `main.m` implementation that is calling `NSApplicationMain()`. If not, a call to `[NSApplication sharedApplication]` will also cause it to be created.

To access the shared instance of NSApplication, use either

```
[NSApplication sharedApplication];
```

or simply use the global variable

```
NSApp
```

To access the app delegate's shared instance, use

```
[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

or simply

```
[NSApp delegate]
```

In the text you quoted, I would assume `appDel` to be a variable that is assigned the return value of `[NSApp delegate]` in order to save a few characters typing when it is used very often.

Comment: actually is this one and I don't get it                                    appDel is an AppDelegate shared instance of your application  
        [appDel.window addSubview: [wikitudeAR start]];

Comment: when i type this: [[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
xcode asking me to replace nsaplication with uiapplication

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't notice the iPhone tag. On an iPhone, it's of course `UIApplication` instead of `NSApplication`, and there's no comparable shorthand for `NSApp`, so you'll always have to write `[UIApplication sharedApplication]`.

Comment: `appDel` in your example would probably be the object returned by `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]`.